# Do all character sets have ASCII in common?

Tags: character-encoding, ascii

The reason I ask is that there's a "standard" for [affix files](https://www.openoffice.org/lingucomponent/affix.readme) that says to read the first line of a file, and it will tell you how the file is encoded:

```
The first line specifies the character set used for both the 
wordlist and the affix file (should be all uppercase). 

For example:

SET ISO8859-1
```

That strikes me as being both unreasonable and unreliable, unless all character sets have the 7-bit ASCII range in common, which would allow you to "taste" up to the first newline byte(s): `0xA` or `0xD`.

But I have no idea if the ASCII range is common to all character sets or not.

Comment: Technically speaking it's not, no. Practically speaking most encodings you'll encounter in use today are. If there's a standard that tells you to do this, then it's safe to assume that all files that are supposed to work with this standard share that constraint, no? Set a sensible limit for the line length when "tasting" so you're not being thrown off by random garbage files (including non-ASCII based encodings).

Comment: I put "standard" in quotes, because it's not a real standard, as far as I know. It's probably more of a convention. I agree that most will probably have the ASCII characters in common, but I don't think the convention disallows non-ISO-8859-* character sets, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) is non-ASCII based, and is still used in IBM mainframe-based software environments with extreme backwards-compatibility requirements.

More popular are [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) and [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32), which although ASCII-based, are backwards-incompatible due to all the extra `00` bytes.

Still, there are only a few ways to encode the Basic Latin alphabet.  (What distinguishes most of the hundreds of character encodings that exist are their handling of accented and non-Latin letters.)  So, the program that reads these files only needs to handle a few possible ways of encoding the word `SET`:

- `53 45 54` for ASCII-based encodings (Windows-1252, UTF-8, etc.)
- `E2 C5 E3` for EBCDIC-based encodings (*if* these are considered worth supporting at all)
- `00 53 00 45 00 54` for UTF-16BE
- `53 00 45 00 54 00` for UTF-16LE
- `00 00 00 53 00 00 00 45 00 00 00 54` for UTF-32BE
- `53 00 00 00 45 00 00 00 54 00 00 00` for UTF-32LE

The decoder could simply look for them all.